# converting the value of an object/array into a string in javascript

Tags: mysql, string, node.js, object

I'm trying to do a login service on a website, but I'm having trouble accessing the data from mysql. At the moment I am only taking the password for the user concerned, to compare it to the user input. However, the password is being returned as an array of length 1 from what I can tell (results.length gives an output of 1). When I try to output the value I get [ { pword: 'ghfg' } ]. I have tried to convert it to a String using the toString() method, but when I output the value it returns [object Object].

I have used the loop of 
    `for (var key in results)
         {
          var value = results[key]
          }`

and when I output the value I get { pword: ghfg }.

This is good, but when I output the type it says object, and I'm faced with the same problem of trying to convert it to a String and get the value: [object Object].

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I'm presuming it's something simple I just haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var key in results) {
  var value = results[key].pword;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString` rarely gives a useful response, especially with objects. You need to convert it to a human-readable format. The obvious choice is JSON, which shares its syntax with Javascript objects.

To get this, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This is available in all modern browsers, but you may need to patch it into old browsers if you think they're likely to be used.

With that said, I'm struggling to work out what your code actually looks like, with the exception of the line you've posted. It may be that there's a better way to do this, but I can't tell without a bit more context/

Comment: I thought he just wanted the value. I like your answer better now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now outputting something I can use which is all I could have asked for!

Comment: @mart87 Glad to have helped.